# I have a problem with the base SQLITE3, how to solve it?

Tags: python, sqlite

I have such a code Python:

`conn.execute(("UPDATE instagram SET description_photo =? WHERE id="),self.inputDescriptionInstagram,self.idPhoto)`

an error pops up:
conn.execute(("UPDATE instagram SET description_photo =? WHERE id=?"),self.inputDescriptionInstagram,self.idPhoto)
TypeError: function takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

what am I doing wrong, where is the mistake?

self.inputDescriptionInstagram,self.idPhoto to the data transferred using the to definition button. All code is located in the class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also missed '?' after `id=`There should be 2 arguments, 1st sql query , 2nd the parameters I think you should try

```
conn.execute("UPDATE instagram SET description_photo =? WHERE id=?", (self.inputDescriptionInstagram,self.idPhoto))
```

or you can also do like this

```
conn.execute("UPDATE instagram SET description_photo =" + self.inputDescriptionInstagram + " WHERE id= " + self.idPhoto+ )
```

Comment: conn.execute("UPDATE instagram SET description_photo =? WHERE id=?", (self.inputDescriptionInstagram,self.idPhoto)) it worked, the second variant throws errors, Thank you for your help :)